# I am trying to use back tick to call out a function that contains my id and key. But I am getting an error as Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, reactjs

While trying to use backtick I am getting this error in my code.

```
const App =()=>{

  var APP_ID: '2******';
  var APP_KEY: 'f25*************';
  var example_Req : `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are declaring variables with the wrong syntax - use an equal sign instead of a colon.